# How can one detect a brand new fitted unformatted internal hard disk in a laptop

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

I have a HP paivillion dv6646 laptop. Its hard disk drive failed recently. I purchased and got a new internal SATA Toshiba hard drive fitted in this laptop. Obviously since being new, it is unformatted disk.

Would that new disc be recognized during the bootup?

Any settings to be enabled in BiOS before bootup?

I do have the original OS(Windows ) disc for this laptop. How do i install OS on this new fitted internal disc?

Comment: Ok.  So, you got a new hard drive and installed it.  Is that all you have done?  Have you tried to boot to the original disc you mention?  If you did try and it failed, what happened?  Are we talking about a DV 6646us that was sold with Windows Vista?  Or was yours an earlier version that came with XP?  What version of Windows are you trying to install?  When you say you have the original Windows disc, do you mean you have an **actual** Windows Installation disc, or an HP recovery disc?  Or that you have the recovery disc that HP made you burn yourself?

Comment: It's dv6646.Vista.New Internal HDD Not recognized in boot up.

Comment: Not recognized by the BIOS or by the recovery disc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your BIOS will detect the new hard drive, since one of the BIOS's functions is to test for new devices connected to the computer.

If you want to install a new OS onto the laptop (and if you're using a CD to do it), you'll need to make the computer boot by **cd/dvd rom**, which you can accomplish by changing the BIOS settings permanently✝ or by temporarily changing the boot order✝✝.

✝ This setting varies between computers. It might be **F1**, **F2** or even **ESC**. I would check which keybind your BIOS is set to before wildly pressing these.

✝✝ Varies between computers. Though experience tells me this could be **F10** or **F11**. Again, check which keybinding your BIOS has set for this.